# Generating WSDL file from PHP web service

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have developed a simple PHP service with a server and client. The server gets a string from the client and appends the string "Hello" to it and displays the same. Now I am trying to generate the WSDL file for this web service. So far my efforts ended in vain.

My
  Server code ->http://chopapp.com/#vw94hjyf
  client code ->http://chopapp.com/#7ct34o9u

I am a newbie to this PHP web service thing. Any constructive suggestions to auto-generate from the PHP web service is welcome.

**Note:**
I have already written the WSDL for the web service. But I want to auto generate it rather than  writing it manually.